# Assembly with other assembly reference. How does it find it?

Tags: c#

I have created a very simple JSON serializer, and compiled it into its own assembly. My assembly, lets call it `JsonSerializer.dll`, references `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`.

When i add my `JsonSerializer.dll` as a reference in another project and build it, it automatically puts `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in my output directory. I would really like to know how this happens.

I tried clearing my nuget cache and disabling the internet connection to try and deduce what happens, but it still finds the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` somehow.

The only reference to Newtonsoft.Json i can find in `JsonSerializer.dll`, is by inspecting the IL code, which has an "assembly extern Newtonsoft.Json" reference. But i cant figure out how that is put into play.

Comment: nuget packages are cached locally in your home dir `.nuget` directory.

Comment: yeah, but i cleared it, and it still fetches the Newtonsoft.Json library somehow; even with no internet connection :)